# MongoDB Aggregation Framework: $project: use a value of a doc as the name of a key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

I have the following **subdocument**:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "url":"mysite.com",
    "views": 
     [
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":"01-01-2015"},
       {"ip":"2.2.2.2","date":"01-01-2015"},
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":"01-01-2015"},
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":"01-01-2015"}
     ]
}
```

and the following **query** so far:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$views"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$views.ip",
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

that returns the following **result**:

```
[  
  {  
    "_id":"2.2.2.2",
    "count":1
  },
  {  
    "_id":"1.1.1.1",
    "count":3
  }
]
```

I would like to achieve the following output **result**, *or quite similar*:

```
[  
  {  
    "2.2.2.2": 1,
    "1.1.1.1": 3
  }
]
```

where each **key** would be every `_id`, and it's **value** their associated `count`. Is this possible to achieve?

**I've tried so far** adding at the end of the `aggregate` pipe a `$project` document like this one:

```
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "$_id": "$count"
    }
}
```

but it seems this doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve my desired query **result** or should I just stick to what I did so far and forget about it because it is not possible to achieve so?

Comment: Not possible with the aggregation framework, you may need to create the hash keys off the results by iterating the [`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) cursor using [`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach) or [`map()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.map/) and transforming the properties in the documents.

Comment: @charliebrownie sorry to tell you but the answer to your question is in there.

Comment: Hey @user3100115, I 've given it a more in depth read, and you are right! Sorry for that. It seems that this cannot be done with the `Aggregation Framework` but with `Map-Reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

The aggregation framework cannot output a **key** name from a **value**. The best place to do this in our application layer. As suggested in the comment, you could use either use the map reduce framework or `forEach` to achieve this, however, their performance is generally poorer, in particular in sharded environments, see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/#map-reduce-javascript-functions).

Comment: I don't see how this answer the question.